# cannot open shared library during execution

Tags: shared-libraries, runtime-error

I compiled my program as follows:

```
mpicc b_eff_io.c -o b_eff_io2 -I/scratch/irodero/papi/include -L/scratch/irodero/papi/src -lpapi -lm


 41125309    4 drwxr-xr-x  3 irodero users    4096 May  3 23:14 .
    39649287    4 drwxr-xr-x 12 irodero users    4096 May  3 00:27 ..
    41126356    4 drwxr-xr-x  2 irodero users    4096 May  3 23:10 kk
    41125409 2632 -rw-r--r--  1 irodero users 2688796 May  3 00:27 libpapi.a
    41126357  764 -rwxr-xr-x  1 irodero users  774486 May  3 23:14 libpapi.so
    41126358  764 -rwxr-xr-x  1 irodero users  774486 May  3 23:14 libpapi.so.4
    41126359  764 -rwxr-xr-x  1 irodero users  774486 May  3 23:14 libpapi.so.4.0.0
    41125398   84 -rw-r--r--  1 irodero users   79032 May  3 00:27 libperfctr.a
    41126360   76 -rwxr-xr-x  1 irodero users   72623 May  3 23:14 libperfctr.so
    41126361   76 -rwxr-xr-x  1 irodero users   72623 May  3 23:14 libperfctr.so.6
    41126362   76 -rwxr-xr-x  1 irodero users   72623 May  3 23:14 libperfctr.so.6.2.6.40
    41125312 1216 -rw-r--r--  1 irodero users 1238236 May  3 00:27 libpfm.a
    41126363 1028 -rwxr-xr-x  1 irodero users 1046742 May  3 23:14 libpfm.so
    41126364 1028 -rwxr-xr-x  1 irodero users 1046742 May  3 23:14 libpfm.so.3
    41126365 1028 -rwxr-xr-x  1 irodero users 1046742 May  3 23:14 libpfm.so.3.9.0
```

However I got this error:

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libpapi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe...

- the library is in use
- the permissions are incorrect
- it does not exist
- it's not in the library search path

Comment: but i'm trying to link statically... why does this error show up ?

Comment: .so files are not what you are looking for then. You should be linking with the .a file.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

```
$ ./a.out 
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libpapi.so: cannot open shared object file:     No such file or directory

$locate libpapi.so
/usr/local/lib64/libpapi.so
/usr/local/lib64/libpapi.so.4
/usr/local/lib64/libpapi.so.4.1.4.0
```

Creating a symbolic link to /usr/lib fixed the issue

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libpapi.so /usr/lib/libpapi.so
```